# How to get value of url inside a function in golang

Tags: go, router, gorilla

I have this router function with mux:

```
func InitRouter() {
    r := http.NewServeMux()
    r.HandleFunc("/{id}", getWords)
    log.Fatal(http.ListenAndServe(":8000", r))
}
```

I want that the getWords function output the value of id, for instance:
if url is [www.abc.com/cat](http://www.abc.com/cat),   getWords will output cat
if url is [www.abc.com/3](http://www.abc.com/3)      getWords will output 3

I looked through out internet I didnt find explainations

Comment: http.ServeMux does not support URL path parameters. You have to either implement it yourself (e.g. using regex capturing groups) or use external library like gorilla mux.

Comment: Either wait for the next Go version, use a 3rd-party router or implement it yourself (3 lines of code).

Answer (score 2):

The current version of http.ServeMux does parse path parameters.  Write code to parse out path parameters.  Here's an example:

```
func InitRouter() {
    r := http.NewServeMux()
    // The path / matches all paths.
    r.HandleFunc("/", getWords)
    log.Fatal(http.ListenAndServe(":8000", r))
}

func getWords(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    // Trim the / prefix to get the id
    id := strings.TrimPrefix(r.URL.Path, "/")
    fmt.Fprintf(w, "the id is %s", id)
}
```

If `/` is not allowed in the id, then respond with an error when id contains a `/`.

```
func getWords(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    id := strings.TrimPrefix(r.URL.Path, "/")
    if strings.Contains(id, "/") {
        http.Error(w, "Not Found", http.StatusNotFound)
        return
    }
    fmt.Fprintf(w, "the id is %s", id)
}
```

Comment: When matching URLs one should almost always use RawPath instead of Path. There's usually a difference between foo/bar/baz and foo%2Fbar/baz. Path doesn't distinguish the two.

Answer (score 0):

Please use `github.com/gorilla/mux`, and add using `go get -u github.com/gorilla/mux`:

Code:

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "log"
    "net/http"
    "github.com/gorilla/mux"
)

func getWords(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    vars := mux.Vars(r)
    id := vars["id"]
    fmt.Println("ID:", id)   // for stdout
    w.Write([]byte("ID: " + id))
}

func InitRouter() {
    r := mux.NewRouter()  // gorilla mux new router
    r.HandleFunc("/{id}", getWords)
    log.Fatal(http.ListenAndServe(":8000", r))
}

func main() {
    InitRouter()
}
```

Output (on Terminal & Browser):

```
ID: 3
ID: cat
```